# AWs Cloudsearch Complex filtering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

When filtering data in Cloudsearch, I am using:

```
&fq=(and type:1 sub_type:0)
```

What I want to do is add more to this but instead of being AND it needs to be OR

So that the query is like:

```
filter: 
      type=1
   and
      sub_type=0
   and
      color=red or color = blue
```

How would I construct the filter to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would look like this (the boolean operators can take any number of args):

```
fq=(and type:1 sub_type:0 (or color:'red' color:'blue'))
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-compound-queries.html